# Code coverage issue with Link files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are using link files in one of the project to reuse the existing code which is written in another project.

In current project we are using very few functions from these link files and we have written unit tests for used functions. but because of unused functions, we have very low code coverage.

have you come across such a scenario where the linked files are creating a code coverage issue (while they have coverage in the original project)?

Comment: I think theres a attribute for ignoring a file for codecoverage.

Comment: You can exclude certain assemblies from code coverage, if you need to.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj159530.aspx) for details.

Comment: If I add attribute to class then Main Project's code coverage will also be impacted. I want to keep the Main Project's code coverage intact. Is there any way to exclude code coverage in my current project for these link files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute on the classes within a pre-processor directive like #if ChildProject. And set the conditional compilation symbol only in the Child project properties…That way, that attribute will only kick in when ChildProject complies, and when MainProject compiles, it will ignore that attribute …